# How can I create and combine "InstallDate" Output with "xxx Days Ago" in batch?

Tags: batch-file, time, wmic, days

Below mentioned batch file displays InstallDate (Converted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('WMIC OS GET InstallDate /format:value') do (
    @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ("%%A") do (
        Call :ConvertDate %%B
    )>"%temp%\%~n0.txt"
)
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('Type "%temp%\%~n0.txt"') do ( set InstallDate=%%D )
echo Install Date: %InstallDate%
pause
::**********************************************************************
Rem Function for Converting WMI Dates to a Standard Date-Time Format
:ConvertDate <Date>
(
    echo WScript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("%~1"^)
    echo Function WMIDateStringToDate(Mydate^)
    echo  WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(Mydate, 5, 2^) ^& "/" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 7, 2^) ^& "/" ^& Left(Mydate, 4^) _
    echo  ^& " " ^& Mid (Mydate, 9, 2^) ^& ":" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 11, 2^) ^& ":" ^& Mid(Mydate,13, 2^)^)
    echo End Function
)>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
Del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
```

Output:

```
Install Date: 24/05/2020 12:54:28
```

Now, For this I am trying to create and combine Desire Output like:

```
Install Date: 24/05/2020 12:54:28 (114 Days Ago)
```

I have tried several things but failed. is there any way to do this in batch?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're already using [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh) for your date conversion, you may as well use it to retrieve the [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi) information too.

Here's a single hybrid [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which should do that for you, without the need to write a [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) file, run it, then delete it:

```vb
<!-- :
@"%__APPDIR__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"
@Pause & GoTo :EOF
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        dtmInstalled   = ParseDat(objItem.InstallDate)
        numInstalled   = DateDiff("n",dtmInstalled,ParseDat(objItem.LocalDateTime))
        numInstDays    = (numInstalled \ 60) \ 24
        strMessage     = "Install Date: " & dtmInstalled
        If numInstDays     = 0 Then
            strMessage     = strMessage & " (Today)"
        ElseIf numInstDays > 1 Then
            strMessage     = strMessage & " (" & numInstDays & " Days Ago)"
        Else
            strMessage     = strMessage & " (" & numInstDays & " Day Ago)"
        End If
    Next
    WScript.Echo strMessage
    WScript.Quit

    Function ParseDat(ByVal strDate)
        strYear  = Left(strDate,4)
        strMonth = Mid(strDate,5,2)
        strDay   = Mid(strDate,7,2)
        strDat   = strDay & "/" & strMonth & "/" & strYear
        strHour  = Mid(strDate,9,2) - strTimeShift
        strMins  = Mid(strDate,11,2)
        strSecs  = Mid(strDate,13,2)
        strTime  = strHour & ":" & strMins & ":" & strSecs
        ParseDat = strDat & " " & strTime
    End Function
    </Script></Job>
```

*As you've made no attempt at calculating the number of days yourself, I will not be explaining any of the above, modifying it, or adjusting it should you decide to modify your question post submission.*